# Trying to read data from a table by combining the properties of 2 different tables

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, html-table, css-selectors

Here is the HTML for two tables that I am trying to read info from.

Table 1 has the heading that I am looking for:

```
<div>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><h3 id="00Qw000000cxlth_RelatedNoteList_title">**My table**</h3></td> // table Head is stored in this table
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table> 
</div>
```

Table 2 is where the data is present and I read to store all the TD cells data in the string array. Table 2 is present right below table 1 but they are two different tables.

```
<div>
<div id="00Qw000000cxlth_RelatedNoteList_body" class="pbBody"> //div id changes dynamically everytime for a different record.
<table class="list">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Attachment</td>
<td>Requirement info for status</td>
<td>09/07/2014 20:34</td>
<td>John doe</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**My question: Is it possible to search for the heading of first table ("My table") and than fetch all the table data from the following table (table 2).**

```
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//table[@class='list']//td"));
  int count = rows.size();
  System.out.println(rows.size());
  String[] array = new String[count];


  for (int i = 0; i<count; i++)
  {
        array[i] = rows.get(i).getText();
        System.out.println(array[i]);
  }
```

This gives me all the data from the table 2, but it also gives me all the tables info on the page that has @class = 'list' and not just the table with heading = 'My table'

**Tried the following solutions without any luck**

```
//div//table[//h3[contains(text(),'My table')]]//table//td[following-sibling::td] - Gets way more matches than just from one table.
```

Comment: leave me a comment if you are still unsure about how to do it. :-)

Comment: @YuZhang leaving a comment :). Should i try it like this based on the info:    `//table[h3 = 'My table']//td[preceding-sibling::td]`

Comment: why use preceding? I thought Table 1 is ahead of Table 2? You want to use Table 1 as the reference, right? So you should use following-sibling instead. I think.

Comment: `//table[h3 = 'My table']//td[following-sibling::td]` - Changed it to this and still no luck (zero matches), am i missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. If your second table and first table are siblings, e.g.

```
<table>1st table</table>
<table>2nd table</table>
```

You can locate the first table first then find the second table using xpath, please follow this link to find more information on how to locate an element using sibling. http://scraping.pro/res/xpath-cheat/xpath_css_dom_recipes.pdf

There are many ways to ***"Uniquely"*** identify a web element, the link above is my favorite selenium cheat sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table.list"));
List<WebElement> rows = table.findElements(By.tagName("tr"));
System.out.println(rows.size());
for (WebElement row : rows)
{
    System.out.println(row.getText().trim());
}
```

This will return the first TABLE that has class = "list". It then loops through all the table rows *of that table* and prints the innerText.

Comment: thank you for the response, but the requirement is that it has to look for the table 1 heading first "My table" and then proceed to find the td from the following table ("table 2"), your solution only looks at table 2 and not the combination of both the tables. Please correct me if i am wrong,

Comment: Understood... is a TABLE with class list not unique on the page? If so, then this will work. If not, the I need to rework my answer... :)

Comment: Correct, it is _not_ unique and hence is fetching all the td for every table on the page.

Comment: Well that can't be completely true because your HTML shows the first table doesn't have the list class. :)  Try running driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table.list")).size() and see what that returns? The way you have your XPath specified, you are getting every TD that is inside table.list. If you pull the first (or whatever) table.list and *then* get the TDs, you will only get the right ones.

Comment: Is the TABLE that you want always in the same position on the page? If so you can do `List<WebElement> tables = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table.list")); tables.get(n);` where n is the index of the TABLE you want.

Answer (score 0):

Use below xpath

```
  //div[table/tbody/tr/td/h3[@id='00Qw000000cxlth_RelatedNoteList_title'] or ./div[@id='00Qw000000cxlth_RelatedNoteList_body']/table[@class='list']/tbody/tr/td]
```

I have created a html page according to same HTML tags you have provided above.

[image]

This xpath return you 1st table heading as well as 2nd table all data. Then extract it all using *WebElement List* and further you can write your code according to your need.

If it is not working for you then let me know

Comment: thank you for the response. It locates not only td cells but all the td cells on the page, i found 168 matches based on the xpath provided. There is only one table named "My table" but it seems like it is not considering the same. Am i doing something wrong here?

Comment: 168 data includes your data from 1st table or 2nd table or from both?

Comment: Not just this two tables. it includes every table on the page

Comment: I have updated the xpath again. Please try with this now ... one thing more do your page have duplicate id for "00Qw000000cxlth_RelatedNoteList_title" and "00Qw000000cxlth_RelatedNoteList_body" . please get back to me if you still facing problem